# как правильно составить ajax запрос в wp?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, json

создаю функцию обновления даты в поле базы данных wp.

функция из actions.php обновляет дату до текущей, но не получается привязать к кнопке
, ***чтобы обновлялось по клику*** зарегистрированным пользователем.
что в этом коде неправильно и чего недостаёт?
как обезопасить такой код?

**только начал изучать ajax, поэтому прошу сильно не ругать**.

код actions.php

```
function update_post($up_date) { 

global $post;

$id = get_queried_object_id(); // id

$blogtime = current_time('d.m.Y H:i:s'); //-3 часа

$new_date_insert = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("$blogtime"."-300")); //now

$ad = array(
    'ID' => $id,
    'post_date' => $new_date_insert
);

$up_date = wp_update_post($ad);
die();
}

if( is_admin() ) {

add_action('wp_ajax_click_update_post', 'update_post');

}
```

код ajax находится в файле с кнопкой

```
 <input type="button" name="up" id="up" metod="post" class="btn_orange" value="обновить" />




<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){  
                $(input).on('click', '#up', function() {
                        $.ajax({  
                            type: 'POST',
                            url : '/includes/actions.php',
                            cache: false, 
                            data: {action: 'click_update_post',

                            },
                            success: function(response){
    alert('data' + response);
    }
                    });  
    return false;
    });  
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: `$(input).on(...)` заменить на `$(document).on(...)`, и в actions.php у вас выводится что-то? я думаю она должна возвращать время, которое вы и будете подставлять

Comment: В actions.php ничего не должно выводится , там находится функция php для обновления поля (дата создания произвольного поста)

Comment: Ошибки разные. Но грубейшая - никогда не лезьте в ядро! Забудьте про его существование. Вам там нечего делать. Почитайте о том, как надо создавать ajax в WP: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/

Comment: get_queried_object() работает только внутри цикла WordPress, в ajax он работать не должен.

Comment: Спасибо! Придется хорошенько браться за изучение ajax, вещь то нужная! о том, как надо создавать ajax в WP